# How to get file system path of the context root of any application

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am working on web application.I invoke on my jsp `request.getContextPath()`, but strangely I got address `/streetshop`.

Then I am appending some path as `request.getContextPath() + "abc"` and create folder.

Then its creating folder in `D://` instead of my webapplication folder.

Please, tell me, I want to upload an image in put it in my `web-application root/images/images.gif`.

Comment: Can you paste code that you use to create a folder?

Comment: follwing code I am using for storing image ...String imagePath= request.getContextPath()+ System.getProperty("file.separator") + p_form.getCategorySelect() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + p_form.getSubCatSelect() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + order_id +System.getProperty("file.separator") ; after this I will use this string for creating file and save.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You mix things up here. `HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()` returns your web application root path. In your example this is `/streetshop`, so your URL may look similar to `www.myapp.com/streetshop`. If you want to access the internal file system path, you must obtain it from the `ServletContext` using [`request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29). This should return the location of your WAR files' `WebContent` folder.

Keep in mind that if you modify contents of this path during runtime, you're going to loose everything when redeploying your application.