# Go to a specific directory in Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, java-io

i have a app folder in tomcat webapps named BankApp, and there is a temp directory in it.

I want to get all the files in temp folder

I tried this :

```
File file = new File(path + "/temp/");

File[] list = file.listFiles();

for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)    
{
    out.println(list[i].getName() + "<br/>");
}
```

but its not working, i mean giving null error

is it the right way to go to that folder ? i.e. BankApp\temp

Thanks !

Comment: Please add the following code to your servlet and tell us what the result is: out.println("dir=" + new File(".").getAbsolutePath()). Then realise that the value of path isn't correct and accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a final answer, from the JavaDoc for [`java.util.File.listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29):

> An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory**, or if an I/O error occurs.

Are you sure the statement `path + "/temp/"` returns a valid (existing) path?

Edit: You must correctly identify the root path of your *BankApp*. You can do this by calling `ServletContext.getRealPath("/")`. See my [answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460608/how-to-get-file-system-path-of-the-context-root-of-any-application/7460693#7460693).

Comment: no its not. It is returning null. Thats my question how do i go to the temp folder loacted inside BankApp folder ?

Comment: @Nitin Kabra: How do you determine the value of your `path` variable? Please update your question with the corresponding code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Define "it's not working" -- what happens?

If you want the files in the temp directory why do you `getParentFile` and list the files in that directory instead?

Comment: Where does the null error occur? Have you verified the path you're creating is correct?

Comment: is it the right way to go to that folder ? i.e. BankApp\temp .

Comment: Then the directory you're trying to list doesn't exist (or possibly you don't have access; not sure). Again, are you sure the path you're attempting to access is correct?

Comment: it exists and i have access too. when i list all directories of BankApp folder, it gives me the temp directory too. but when i add /temp and try to access it, returns null.

Comment: Show us the full path you're accessing, and the `ls -al` output of the same path--if the path exists, and the user running the app server has access to it, AFAIK it pretty much has to work.

Comment: am on Windows and path to temp is D:\Apache\webapps\BankApp\temp

Comment: Not much else to tell you other than what I've already said--as the other answerer stated, there aren't too many conditions under which you'll get a `null` back.