# Accessing a file within the context root of an application in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have been attempting to obtain the context root of an application which is being deployed by using the app base of the host and doc base of the context.

```
try {
    if (context != null) {
        //  Value of the following variable depends on various conditions. Sometimes you get just the webapp
        //  directory name. Sometime you get absolute path the webapp directory or war file.
        String webappFilePath;
        Host host = (Host) context.getParent();
        String appBase = host.getAppBase();
        File canonicalAppBase = new File(appBase);
        if (canonicalAppBase.isAbsolute()) {
            canonicalAppBase = canonicalAppBase.getCanonicalFile();
        } else {
            canonicalAppBase = new File(PathUtils.getCatalinaBase().toString(), appBase).getCanonicalFile();
        }

        String docBase = context.getDocBase();
        File webappFile = new File(docBase);
        if (webappFile.isAbsolute()) {
            webappFilePath = webappFile.getCanonicalPath();
        } else {
            webappFilePath = (new File(canonicalAppBase, docBase)).getPath();
        }
        return Paths.get(webappFilePath);
    } else {
        throw new ApplicationServerException("Context cannot be null");
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new ApplicationServerException("Error while generating webapp file path", ex);
}
```

The purpose of accessing the context root was to access a custom configuration file I have added to /WEB-INF folder.

When researching further, I discovered the following simple ways of accessing the a resource located within the app's folder.

[How to get file system path of the context root of any application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460608/how-to-get-file-system-path-of-the-context-root-of-any-application)

But when I use the method defined here, I am always getting a null value for the context root.

```
Path contextWebAppDescriptor = Paths.
                        get(context.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"), Constants.WEBAPP_RESOURCE_FOLDER,
                                Constants.WEBAPP_DESCRIPTOR);
```

Please consider the two constants:

```
public static final String WEBAPP_RESOURCE_FOLDER = "WEB-INF";
public static final String WEBAPP_DESCRIPTOR = "wso2as-web.xml";
```

Have I misunderstood the proper usage of this method? Can we only use the method

```
context.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

only within the web app code in order to function properly?

Answer (score 1):

A better approach, IMHO, will be to use [`ServletContext.getResourcePaths()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourcePaths-java.lang.String-) method.

This, essentially:

> Returns a directory-like listing of all the paths to resources within
>   the web application whose longest sub-path matches the supplied path
>   argument.

So, to get all the content inside your `WEB-INF` folder, you could do:

```
Set<String> paths = servletContext.getResourcePaths("/WEB-INF/");
```

Then iterate through `paths` to get the relevant resource. Resource ending `/` indicates a sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by using the [ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) which can be used to obtain an [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) for the specified resource.

This is simply the way in which Tomcat itself performs the reading of its web.xml as far as I know. And it has to be noted that this method is effective at the LifeCycle event CONFIGURE_START_EVENT rather than BEFORE_START_EVENT.

Comment: Then your question is very misleading. Read the title.